# How to fill an empty dataframe with certain categories in a double iteration?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First of all, sorry for the rather vague title but I didn't know how to describe the problem. I'm currently working with a large dataset of biodiversity of organisms and I have a specific problem.

To give some background:Each row of the dataset is a type of organism and the columns are the taxonomic levels (kingdom, class, genus,..) and the samples (a measure for the amount that the organism is present in that sample.

So one row has several taxonomic levels (=strings) and then how much that organism is present in the samples, the number of reads (=integers).

Per sample I would like to sum the amount of organisms (the integer measure) per class (=taxonomic level). Note that the class is not unique for each row/organism and 50 organisms (=50 rows) can have the same class, while having different other taxonomic levels (e.g. genus).

```
classes=pd.unique(pd["class_name"])      ###the different classes (=106), the "class_name" column contains the class of each organism in the df.

x=-1
y=48
class_samples=pd.DataFrame(columns=["class"]) ###empty dataframe to fill with only one column at this point

while x < len(classes)-1:    ###iterate over the classes, start at class 0
    x=x+1
    req_class=pd.loc[pd.class_name == classes[x]] 

###Here (above) all rows of all samples with classes[x] are selected --> so everytime one class is selected and in this req class I want to sum all the reads(=measure) per sample (see while loop below)

    while y < len(pd.columns)-1: ###iterate over the columns = samples, start at column 49 --> for each unique class (=x) I want to iterate over all columns = samples starting at column 49 (=y))

        y=y+1

        class_samples=class_samples.append(pd.DataFrame({"class":[classes[x]],pd.columns[y]:[sum(req_class[df.columns[y]])]})) 
###with this code I would like to fill the class_samples dataframe with each of the classes under the "class"column and I want to create a new column for each of the samples and this column contains the sum of the measure of all organisms with the specified class (=x)
```

This code unfortunately does not work and I've tried a lot but I can't get it to work.

So in the new dataframe class_samples I would like to have a column with each class and for each class I want the sum of the measure (=sample columns in the original df) per sample.

I hope that I've explained the problem clear enough! I've added some comments in the code.

[Click here for example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbVMT.jpg) ###My reputation is too low to include an image

Comment: Did you try `groupby` method of the pandas dataframe ?

Comment: Could you write a simple example and your expected result to illustrate what you want to do ?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've added a link to a picture. Click on "Click here for example picture". (reputation too low for image). Does this clarify the problem?

Comment: I've been trying the `groupby` method and it is very promising. I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: `groupby` works, thanks!